# How to add a new method in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

In the Nautilus System Browser (Pharo 6) there's a right-click command to `Add package...` as well as `Add class...` and even `Add protocol...`, but I can't find anywhere a way to `Add method...`.

Where is that command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pharo, adding a method is not as explicit as the other elements. To add a new method:

1. Select the protocol for the method, and you should see a template in the editor pane:

   ```
   messageSelectorAndArgumentNames
      "comment stating purpose of message"

      | temporary variable names |
      statements
   ```
2. Edit this template to make a new method,
3. Save (Right-click **Accept**) it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

In fact, any time you change a method's definition (e.g., `messageSelectorAndArgumentNames`) and save it in the editor (Right-click **Accept** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>), it will **create a new method**.

[image]

For more details, see the section 1.3 of [Developing a simple counter](https://www.fun-mooc.fr/c4x/inria/41010/asset/Exo-Counter.pdf) document (emphasis is mine):

> #### Create a method
>
> Now let us create the accessor methods for the instance variable `count`. Start
>   by selecting the class `Counter` in a browser, and make sure the you are editing the instance side of the class (i.e., we define methods that will be sent to
>   instances) by deselecting the Class side radio button.
>
> Create a new protocol by bringing the menu of methods protocol list. Select
>   the newly created protocol. **Then in the bottom pane, the edit field displays
>   a method template laying out the default structure of a method. As a general
>   hint, double click at the end of or beginning of the text and start typing your
>   method. Replace the template with the following method definition:**
>
> ```
> count
>    "return the current value of the value instance variable"
>    ^ count
> ```
>
> This defines a method called `count`, taking no arguments, having a method
>   comment and returning the instance variable `count`. Then choose *accept* in
>   the menu to compile the method.